# Laravel how to get restaurants from database which working now?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I need to implement a feature that allows restaurant managers to set the opening hours for their restaurant. So I have `Restaurant` model (for this case there's only ID).

Also I created the `RestaurantOpeningHour` model that will contain the data for the restaurants:

```
class RestaurantOpeningHour extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'restaurant_id',
        'pickup_type_id',
        'week_day',
        'from_date',
        'until_date',
        'from_hour',
        'until_hour',
        'is_closed'
    ];

    public function restaurant()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Restaurant::class);
    }

    public function pickupType()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(PickupType::class);
    }
}
```

Business requires a feature where restaurant has "default" opening hours and custom opening hours, that will affect only diapason of dates. So each day of a week has its own row in database, but there can be 2 rows for 1 day: "default" row and "custom" row.
Custom row has higher priority than "default" row.

- Default row means that `from_date` and `until_date` are equals to
  `NULL`.
- Custom row means that the row has a diapason between two dates `from_date` and `until_date`.

My goal is to find the restaurants that open now in eloquent way using eloquent scopes. So I need to make an `scopeOpenNow()` scope in the `Restaurant` model which will implement the following logic:

- `where day = current_day`
- `where from_date IS NULL and until_date IS NULL` and `where from_date >= NOW() AND until_date <= NOW()`
- `ORDER BY (from_date IS NOT NULL, until_date IS NOT NULL) DESC`
- `where from_hour <= NOW() AND until_hour > NOW()`
- `LIMIT 1` because if there will be both of default and custom row for a day, then we need to take only custom row and check it about opening hours.

Now I stuck with the problem about `LIMIT 1`. I don't understand how to make a scope which will implement all items from the list above.

I would appreciate any help :)

Comment: to limit by 1 you can use `take(1)` I would also combine date and time into a single timestamp field which would make the rest of your query easier.

Comment: Also the query `where from_date IS NULL and until_date IS NULL and where from_date >= NOW() AND until_date <= NOW()` doesn't make any sense, how can you return something that is null and greater than the current date? are these supposed to be different columns?

Comment: @Chris no. It means that restaurant has a default schedule, like "We work from 10am till 6pm in Monday". And also it has a special schedule, like "We work from 10am till 4pm from 10th of March till 17th of March". And special schedule has higher priority than default schedule. So I have to select both of schedule types that matches with current date and then sort it by priority and select only first row. So if the restaurant has a special schedule for current date, sorting will make a special schedule as the first row, so `LIMIT 1` will allow us to get needed row.

Comment: I don't understand how you will get those default times if the field's are NULL. Can you edit your question and add in some sample data?

Comment: @Chris like `(from_date < NOW() AND until_date >= NOW()) OR (from_date IS NULL AND until_date IS NULL)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure I fully understand, it would be better if you could provide some example data to work with.

This should get you started:-

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Restaurant extends Model
{
    public function scopeOpenNow($query)
    {
        $now = Carbon::now();
        $dayOfTheWeek = Carbon::now()->dayOfWeek;

        return $query->where(['day', '=', $dayOfTheWeek],
            ['from_date', '>=', $now], ['from_hour', '<=' , $now],
            ['until_date', '<=', $now], ['until_hour', '>',$now])
            ->orWhereNull('from_date')
            ->orderBy('from_date', 'ASC')
            ->take(1)
            ->get();
    }
}
```